# algorithms and run-time analysis

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, runtime

A file (included with two examples) is a list of banned number intervals. A line that contains, for example, 12-18, indicates that all numbers 12 to (inclusive) 18 are prohibited. The intervals may overlap.
We want to know what the minimum number is.
Use variables to analyze run-time (not necessarily need all them):

• N: Maximum (not maximum permissible) number; So the numbers are between 0 and N

• K: number of intervals in a file

• M: width of maximum interval.

A. There is an obvious way to solve this problem: we're checking all numbers until we run into the smallest allowed.
• How fast is such an algorithm?

B. You can probably imagine another simple algorithm that uses N bytes (or bits) of memory.
(Hint: strikethrough.)
• Describe it with words. For example, you can make your own assignment (say a few intervals with numbers between 0 and 20), and show the algorithm on them. However, it also draws up a general description.
• How fast is this algorithm? When thinking, use N, K, and M (if you need it).

C. Make an algorithm that does not consume additional memory (more accurately: the memory consumption should be independent of N, K and M), but it is faster than the algorithm under point A.
• Describe it.
• How fast is it? Is it faster than the B algorithm?

D. Now we are interested in how many numbers are allowed (between 0 and N). How would you adjust the above algorithms for this question? What happens to their rates?

```
file = "0-19.txt"
intervals = [tuple(map(int, v.split("-"))) for v in open(file)]
#example# intervals = [(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]#
```

my current code just executes the program but better algorithms for the code i am yet to figure, still need a lot of work to understand, i would need a quick solution code/algorithm for examples A, B, and C and maybe D. Then i can study the time analysis myself. Appreciate help!

```
def generator_intervala(start, stop, step):
    forbidden_numbers = set()
    while start <= stop:
        forbidden_numbers.add(start)
        start += step
    return (forbidden_numbers)


mnozica = set()
for interval in intervals:
    a, b = interval
    values = (generator_intervala(a, b, 1))
    for i in values:
        mnozica.add(i)



allowed_numbers = set()
N = max(mnozica)
for i in range(N):
    if i not in mnozica:
        allowed_numbers.add(i)




print(intervals)
print(mnozica)
print(min(allowed_numbers))
print(max(mnozica))

Output:

[(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
10
19
```

Comment: "i would need full guidance and solutions for examples A, B, and C and maybe D", this is a completely wrong place to ask for something like this.

Comment: I dont need your prejudices, if you cant help then don't reply.

Comment: Actually i dont need quidance, a few better algorithms/ faster solutions would also be okay. I can study them myself and figure. If you can do that is also okay.

Comment: I corrected the tags and my demands.

Comment: Demands? :D What do you think this site is for? Hint: it's not for you, or anyone to make *demands* for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your set approach is needlessly complex:

```
N = 100
ranges = [(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]

do_not_use = set()

for (a,b) in ranges: 
    do_not_use.update(range(a,b+1))          

print(do_not_use)  

print( min(a for a in range(N+1) if a not in do_not_use))
```

Is about all that is needed. Output:

```
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
10
```

This is independend of N it just depends on how many numbers are in the ranges.

Storing only forbidden numbers in a set takes O(1) for checking, using the `min()` buildin over a range to get the minimum.

You can make it faster if you sort your tuples first and then iterate them until you find the first gap making it Θ(N log N) for the sort, followed by Θ(N) for the search:

```
def findme():
    ranges = [(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]
    ranges.sort()  # inplace sort, no additional space requirements
    if ranges[0][0]>0: 
        return 0

    for ((a_min,a_max),(b_min,b_max)) in zip(ranges,ranges[1:]):
        if a_max < b_min-1:
            return a_max+1

    return ranges[-1][1]+1  # might give you N+1 if no solution in 0-N exists
```

---

**`timeit` of yours vs mine:**

Your code uses 2 sets, as well as multiple loops, incremental addition to your set and function calls that makes it slower:

```
N = 100

def findme():
    ranges = [(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]
    ranges.sort()
    if ranges[0][0]>0: 
        return 0

    for ((a_min,a_max),(b_min,b_max)) in zip(ranges,ranges[1:]):
        if a_max < b_min-1:
            return a_max+1

    return ranges[-1][1]+1

def mine():
    ranges = [(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]
    N = 100
    do_not_use = set()

    for (a,b) in ranges: 
        do_not_use.update(range(a,b+1))          

    return min(a for a in range(N+1) if a not in do_not_use)

def yours():
    ranges = [(12, 18), (2, 5), (3, 8), (0, 4), (15, 19), (6, 9), (13, 17), (4, 8)]
    def generator_intervala(start, stop, step):
        forbidden_numbers = set()
        while start <= stop:
            forbidden_numbers.add(start)
            start += step
        return (forbidden_numbers)

    mnozica = set()
    for interval in ranges:
        a, b = interval
        values = (generator_intervala(a, b, 1))
        for i in values:
            mnozica.add(i)

    allowed_numbers = set()
    N = max(mnozica)
    for i in range(N):
        if i not in mnozica:
            allowed_numbers.add(i)

    return min(allowed_numbers)

import timeit
print("yours", timeit.timeit(yours,number=100000))  
print("mine", timeit.timeit(mine,number=100000))
print("findme", timeit.timeit(findme,number=100000))
```

Output:

```
yours 1.3931225209998956
mine 1.263602267999886
findme 0.1711935210005322
```